# How do I generate an apk file from shared library (.so) files?

Tags: android, android-ndk, apk

I am trying to develop an Android app using purely C++. I am following [this guide](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/concepts#na), which uses the android ndk. The last step is building the project with the script `ndk-build` :

> Build and install your Android project as usual. If your native code is in the jni/ directory, the build script automatically packages the .so file(s) built from it into the APK.

From what I understand, the script should generate shared library (.so) files and also link them together with other resources to produce an apk file. But in my case the apk file does **not** get generated. The .so files get compiled and end up in the `libs` folder of my project directory.

Here is my build script (Android.mk, [source](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk)) :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := Test

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp

APP_PLATFORM := android-30

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I'm new to android development and quite lost. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ndk-build doesn't generate an APK and never did. You should still wrap your JNI project in a proper Android one (in Android Studio) and use Android Studio's means (menu/Build/Build APK) to generate the APK.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev When I do it that way, Android Studio complains about a missing CMakeLists.txt, even though the guide never mentioned anything about such file (only Android.mk).

Comment: And yet that's the part that you have to get through. There are two build systems for native code - ndk-build and cmake. You specify which one is used in a gradle file for the project. Read about about the gradle files as applied to Android, specifically the externalNativeBuild element. In a bigger picture, it was a mistake to start Android development from a pure NDK project. You have to navigate the Android building/packaging system anyway, and NDK only complicates things.